# How are the flat/aero bullhorn handelbars called?

Tags: handlebars, bullhorn

I've seen some bikes which look really good (IMHO) with a bullhorn handlebar which is flat and has an aero design.

After some googling I've only found this model which is really expensive:
[image: bontrager]

Do they have some kind of strange name to search them and find something more affordable?

Is it possible to mount normal brake levers in them? (Not in the horns but in the center)

I currently have normal (rounded) bullhorns, but I'd like to get some of this just for aesthetics if I don´t lose functionality.

Comment: If you do a Google image search for something like "Rohan Dennis time trial", you'll see lots of photos showing how the brake levers are mounted.

Comment: These things often go by "base bars" or "base aero bars".

Comment: You might also like http://cinelli.it/en/prodotti/bullhorn/ - the contouring is more subtle but I think more attractive.

Comment: @adam Eberbach that is exactly what I was looking for, it looks like some normal brake lever could be mounted but still has that aero looks. But they still is quiet expenaive and they just call it bullhorn

Comment: @nck Yes - there is easily space for a single lever with fully-opening clamp where the bar is round near the centre. You can fit two levers but if the cables point inwards then they can obstruct each other.

Answer (score 6):

These are one component of *aero* bars, used on  time trail and triathlon bars.

These are used in conjunction with elbow pads and bar extensions that mount on top. The attachment points are visible in the pic you provided.

See this article [Selecting the Right Aerobars for Triathlon](https://beginnertriathlete.com/cms/article-detail.asp?articleid=1414).

Typically brake levers are mounted on the ends of the lower bars, and gear shifters on the ends of the bar extensions.

Aerodynamic bicycle components tent to be expensive because they are predominately used by pros and racers so they also need to be string and light.

Answer (score 4):

"Pursuit bars" would be one name for them, as would "Sprint bars"

They're scandalously expensive because they have to cope with kilowatts of power from a sprinter at full-blast while being lightweight and aero.

You could fake-up the look by using a light space filler like florist's foam or balsa wood cut in a wing profile and butted up behind the tops of your existing bullhorns.  Then wrap with thin bartape or heatshrink for that tight appearance.

You'll never get brake levers on the tops of these bars - people who ride pursuit bars wouldn't use the tops for anything except an elbow rest.   It would be like asking for a coffee-cup holder or a mirror on a TT bike... just "wrong"